# Interfacing Atmega 2560 with 74ls240 inverting buffer

Tags: arduino, c, atmega

I am trying to light up the 7 segment display using inputs to the Port B pins, causing output on the Port k pins, which are inverted using the 74LS240 chip.

[image: Circuit Diagram]

The Arduino is correctly outputting the correct high or low voltage on the Port K pins. However, the problem I have encountered arises when trying to interface the outputs from the Port K pins to the 74ls240 chip. Regardless of whatever the voltage on the Port K pins is, the output from the 74LS240 is always low. However, if I feed the ground voltage from the arduino board, the inverter outputs a high voltage, so I know that the chip is working fine. Below is the pinout and the logic table for the 74LS240.

[image: 74ls240 pinout]

[image]

I have VCC connected to Arduino's 5v pin, and G1, G2, and GND are tied to Arduino's ground pin.

Here is my code for Arduino:

```
// Define Port B Register Pointers
volatile unsigned char* port_b = (unsigned char*) 0x25; 
volatile unsigned char* ddr_b  = (unsigned char*) 0x24; 
volatile unsigned char* pin_b  = (unsigned char*) 0x23; 

//Define Port K Register Pointers
volatile unsigned char* port_k = (unsigned char*) 0x108; 
volatile unsigned char* ddr_k  = (unsigned char*) 0x107; 
volatile unsigned char* pin_k  = (unsigned char*) 0x106; 

int A;
int B;
int C;
int D;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

Serial.begin(9600);

 *ddr_b &= 0x00; //set all pins to input
 *port_b |= 0xFF;// enable poullup resistors

 *ddr_k &= 0xFF;

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

if( *pin_b & 0x01 ){A = 1;} 
  else{A = 0;}

if( *pin_b & 0x02 ){B = 1;}
  else{B = 0;}  

if( *pin_b & 0x04 ){C = 1;}
  else{C = 0;}

if( *pin_b & 0x08 ){D = 1;}
  else{D = 0;} 



if((B==1 || D == 1)&&(A == 1 || C == 0)&&(B == 0 || C == 0)&&(A == 0 || D == 1)&&(A == 1 || B == 0 || D == 0)&&(A == 0 || B == 1 || C == 1)) // Boolean equation if a is 1 FIXED
{*port_k = *port_k & 0xFE;}
else
{*port_k = *port_k | 0x01;}

if((A==1 || B == 1)&&(B==1 || D == 1)&&(A == 1 || C == 1 || D == 1)&&(A == 1 || C == 0 || D == 0)&&(A == 0 || C == 1 || D == 0)) // Boolean equation if b = 1 FIXED
{ *port_k = *port_k | 0x02;}
else
{*port_k = *port_k & 0xFD;}

if((A == 1 || C == 1)&&(A == 1 || D == 0)&&(C == 1 || D == 0)&&(A == 1 || B == 0)&&(A == 0 || B == 1)) // Boolean equation if c = 1 FIXED
{*port_k = *port_k | 0x04;}
else
{*port_k = *port_k & 0xFB;}

if ((A == 0 || C == 1)&&(A == 1 || B == 1 || D == 1)&&(B == 1 || C == 0 || D == 0)&&(B == 0 || C == 1 || D == 0)&&(B == 0 || C == 0 || D == 1)) //Boolean equation if d = 1 FIXED
{*port_k = *port_k | 0x08;}
else
{*port_k = *port_k & 0xF7;}

if((B == 1 || D == 1)&&(C == 0 || D == 1)&&(A == 0 || C == 0)&&(A == 0 || B == 0))// Boolean equation if e = 1 FIXED
{*port_k = *port_k | 0x10;}
else
{*port_k = *port_k & 0xEF;}

if((C == 1 || D == 1)&&(B == 0 || D == 1)&&(A == 0 || B == 1)&&(A == 0 || C == 0)&&(A == 1 || B == 0 || C== 1))// Boolean equation if f = 1 FIXED
{*port_k = *port_k | 0x20;}
else
{*port_k = *port_k & 0xDF;}

if((B == 1 || C == 0)&&(C == 0 || D == 1)&&(A == 0 || B == 1)&&(A == 0 || D == 0)&&(A == 1 || B == 0 || C == 1))// Boolean equation if g = 1 FIXED
{*port_k = *port_k | 0x40;}
else
{*port_k = *port_k & 0xBF;}



Serial.print(A);
Serial.print(B);
Serial.print(C);
Serial.print(D);
Serial.write("\n");

delay(250);




}
```

Essentially, my question is why will the inverter chip not invert an input of a low voltage from the Arduino, yet it will invert a low voltage if I test an input to the chip with Arduino's ground pin?

Edit: here's a partial schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuidOO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is an example of one of the outputs of the controller being fed into the 74ls240 chip.

Comment: Please intend your code correctly

Comment: Did you connect the /1G and /2G (output enable) inputs to ground? Are you using the Arduino IDE and if so, why not use its built-in functionality to simplify your code? Also, you might not need a TTL buffer at all as the ATMEGA 2560 can source more current than the 74LS240.

Comment: Since you are talking about "feeding ground" having an effect it is not clear how the power connections are. Please provide a complete schematic.

Comment: @StarCat This is for a lab, don't have control over the components of the circuit, and not allowed to use library functions

Comment: @thebusybee I have added an edit for a partial schematic

Comment: Your schematic shows the 74LS240's ground connected to its 2G input, but not to theh ATMega's ground.  The 74LS240's Ground, 1G and 2G pins MUST ALL be connected to the ATMega's Ground, and to the power supply's negative terminal.

Comment: Assuming (it looks like it) you are using a common cathode 7 segment device, the most likely issue is the fact that the 74LS240 cannot drive very much current in the high state and therefore the output will not achieve a high state. The datasheet shows 3mA for normal conditions. This makes sense in a TTL world as driving low inputs to the next gates takes significantly more current than driving a successive gate high.

Comment: @PeterSmith why would the chip be unable to invert a low voltage from a micro controller output on port K, yet is able to invert a test input from ground?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect all grounds: the Arduino's GND **and** the driver's GND. In the first place this has nothing to do with "feeding" in the sense of providing power, it is necessary to define a common voltage reference. You surely know that voltages (and digital levels are voltages) are measured against a reference, don't you?

If you power the driver and in that way the LED with the 5V output of your Arduino, this will actually make the ground connection *additionally* a "feeding" power connection.

---

*Note because of @PeterSmith's comment: He's right about the output current for a high state output.*

You will measure "high" without the LEDs connected because the driver has no load, beside your measuring device. If you connect the LEDs the load will try to consume about (5V - 1.5V) / 220 Ohm = 16 mA which the driver can't provide. The output voltage will go down until the current is reached that the driver *can* provide. This will not be the mentioned 3mA because this is the guaranteed value. It will be higher but might be not high enough to make the LED light up.

You might like to consider using a common anode segment LED or the 74HC240 / 74HCT240. The CMOS drivers have a higher current specification.

Answer (score 1):

This line:-

```
*ddr_k &= 0xFF;
```

is wrong. The data direction register is 0x00 by default, so ANDing it with anything will still leave all the pins as inputs. It should be

```
*ddr_k |= 0xFF;
```

or just

```
*ddr_k = 0xFF;
```